# Personality that is loved extremely or hated extremely (word request)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a person that has contrasting opinions about them and their opinions are at opposite ends of the spectrum.

The words *controversial* and *dividing* are not suitable.

**Examples**

> Kyle could not fathom what people think of him, as he either was very popular with loads of friends who could get stuff for free, or very unpopular with no one wanting to talk to him as he was classed as boring or a sociopath. The differing love and hate he received depending on the environment, was at polar extremeties.
>
> Alex on Monday was gossiped about in a good way by several people boosting her status by becoming one of the few people worth talking about positively, but she was shunned by one of her classes.
>
> Sheridan gave a look, and Kayleigh didn't know whether to hug him or slap him.  She could never decipher his true intentions. He was _______

Answer (score 5):

That person [polarizes](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/polarize) opinions. A polarizing person. Although it's [rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=polarizing%20personality%2Ccontroversial%20personality&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpolarizing%20personality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontroversial%20personality%3B%2Cc0) according to ngram.

> to cause people to adopt extreme opposing positions"   ⇒  ■ to
>   polarize opinion"

Comment: "Polarizing _figure_" is the first thing that comes to mind, although [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=polarizing+personality%2Ccontroversial+personality%2C+polarizing+figure&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpolarizing%20personality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontroversial%20personality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpolarizing%20figure%3B%2Cc0) says it's less popular than "controversial personality".

Answer (score 3):

**"Polarising"** (British English) or **"polarizing"** (US English) could be what you're looking for.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of polarize

> : to cause (people, opinions, etc.) to separate into opposing groups

Answer (score 1):

From Google Books...

> *Harry Challenor was a ['Marmite'](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20marmite%20character%22) character: either loved or loathed.*

From Oxford Dictionaries online...

> [**Marmite**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/marmite)  Used in reference to something that tends to arouse strongly positive or negative reactions rather than indifference:
>    *the styling is ‘Marmite’ — some hate it, many love it*
>    *a proper Marmite sitcom, which people are either utterly loving or totally despising*

I don't know if this usage would be understood in Australia, where I think they call this "polarising" yeast spread *Vegemite*.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use the word marmite because it doesn't convey the contrasting extremity of the opinions. If I say "I'm like marmite people either love or or hate me" it doesn't make the person any more unique than anyone else.

Comment: @desbest: I'm afraid I don't understand your point. The very *reason* this usage has been so enthusiastically adopted is because it's a simple metaphor for "contrasting extremity of the opinions" that doesn't require speakers and audience to know obscure "scientific" terms like *polarising*.

Comment: People don't love or hate marmite to the same extent they love or hate a person.

Comment: @desbest: Are you actually familiar with the usage? Or indeed the spread itself? Not that it matters whether you personally don't have such strong opinions about the taste of Marmite as you do about someone like [the odious Donald Trump](http://www.mrconservative.com/2014/09/50020-donald-trump-ditches-political-correctness-slams-muslims-everywhere/), for example. The fact of the matter is that (for BrE speakers, at least), the expression is predicated on the premise that *everyone* has *very, **very** extreme views* about Marmite.

Comment: Yes to both questions. You don't understand me. I'm from Britain so I am familiar with how the word marmite is used from a cultural standpoint. Certain adjectives mean practically the same thing, but are more extreme than others, such as big, large and humungous. All three words describe a big size, but each word is more (or less) extreme than the other. The same applies to the word marmite. The word marmite is a weak word. If someone says that they are like marmite, the listener will not infer from that statement that they polarise opinion and make others cry or obsessed with them.

Comment: @desbest: I'm getting *really* confused now! What would *you* suppose a person meant if they said "I am like Marmite"? I think I can safely say that most of our fellow countrymen would assume the speaker meant people tend to have extreme reactions to him (they either love or hate what he says or does).

Comment: If a person said that, everyone would think the person is chatting shit, trying to become hip and trendy in the same way people pretend to be bisexual or pansexual for attention. Nobody would take that statement seriously if a person said it. By a person proclaiming that they are like marmite, they are trying to show that they are a fascinating and complex character, thus associating themselves with a multitude of positive traits (opinionated, provocative, intelligent, frank, unique, confident, extroverted etc). There's lots of implicit meaning and hidden intentions in spoken english language.

Comment: @desbest: You have some strange ideas. I don't think this discussion is going to get anywhere useful.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, I know I'm like seven years late to this, but whatever. Maybe you're looking for the word "ambivalence"? Ambivalence means, according to my best friend, Google.com, a "state of having mixed feelings or contradictory ideas about something or someone"

Comment: "He was *ambivalence*" This doesn't work; we don't describe people as such. "Ambivalent" is used that way but means something completely different.